# RedirectToAction not working at all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

In the AccountController, in the end of a method I have:

```
RedirectToAction("EveryView", "Account");
```

In the same controller file I have this method:

```
public ActionResult EveryView()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

But this method never gets called. I have a breakpoint on '{' and it never gets hit!

Comment: This may not be the issue but if it's within the same `Controller`, you can just use `RedirectToAction("EveryView");`

Comment: @Rondel I tried that and it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you just have `RedirectToAction()`? Or `return RedirectToAction(...)`. I tried it and with the `return` it worked fine.

Comment: Do you have any attributes on the `Action` like `[HttpPost]` or anything? Do you get any errors when it hits the `RedirectToAction` or does it just not do anything.

Comment: @Rondel I don't get error, it just doesn't do anything. I don't have [HttpPost] but even if I put it it still doesn't work.

Comment: @SimonLinder I don't have return because my method is void. Is there any way I can make a view show without return?

Comment: @Srcee it has to return the `ActionResult` for it to return the View.

Comment: Yes, it has to be a method that returns `ActionResult`...

Comment: @SimonLinder you should put your comment in an answer

Comment: @Rondel: Why because of the reputation? Just want to help...

Comment: @SimonLinder Why? Because it helps other people find the right answer without having to look through comments, especially if the OP hits the big green tick, then you help not just this person but everyone else.

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling only RedirectToAction("EveryView", "Account"); ? If that is the case, it might not go to the action. It just calls the action and resumes to show the view. Instead, you would have to specify "return". You might write:  return RedirectToAction("EveryView", "Account");

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Humm…difficult to see (or say) what the problem is since the code seems pretty trivial.

Perhaps a little debugging might help!
Try creating a new TestController have inside the default Index() ActionResult do this:

```
return RedirectToAction("EveryView", "Test");
```

Then, create the EveryView() ActionResult method and set your break point.

```
public ActionResult EveryView()
{
    return View();
}
```

If you try http://localhost/Test/Index what happens? Does it work?

If that doesn’t work, perhaps you may want to look at your Routes and make sure you have no special Routes define that could make things break.

Alternatively, you could, inside your `Global.asax` add this method:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
}
```

And set a break point on the line to catch any unknown errors.

Comment: i had the same problem, in my case it was the error, so i debugged it as @Vlince suggested in Global.asax file and i got the error

Answer (score 69):

you have put 'return' else it won't redirect.

`return RedirectToAction("EveryView", "Account");`

Comment: Good pick up!!! This was killing me. Because the code still runs and just completely passes through the RedirectToAction line without crashing!!! Very hard to debug and realise... Thanks

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Easy thing to miss, and no error message was thrown on screen. Just something we need to remember, adding 'return' at the beginning.

Comment: Aaaargh! I owe you £5 Bonanza.

Comment: Good pick up :)

Comment: This is a great answer and thank you.  However, can you provide a reference that explains this behavior?  i.e. "why" must we "return" - and why does something named "Redirect" not?

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem too in my recent project. I resolved it finally by adding [AllowAnonymous] on the redirected action, because the controller decorated with [Authorize] attribute, and at this point the user is not logged in. Hope this is a help.

Comment: Helped, had a minor bug in AuthorizeCore, derived / `overridden` from `AuthorizeAttribute`.. Thnx

Comment: I'd like to see more on how you got past this. I have an authorize tag as well on my landing page. when the user logs in. The authorization is enacted just before calling the redirectToAction.  I suspected it was something in my AuthorizeCore.  Any sample code would be a big plus. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was because a custom MustBeLoggedIn filter I had added was not allowing the redirect to that method, similar to user2192287.

This meant that I the filter was redirecting me back to the action I was starting from.

This may have been petko_stankoski's problem as it was in their Account controller.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I've just removed the post attribute [HttpPost] from the function to where I've redirected.

Comment: That makes the function GET (the default). It's not a good solution.

Comment: Yes it will work, but it's not a good solution. I want my method to be POST, not GET. I'm working by the RESTful principles.

Answer (score 1):

If the Action method doesn't gets invoked, it could be because the method is registered for HttpPost but u are sending HttpGet request. So, better keep the method to accept both request using  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]

Answer (score 1):

you have to return it

```
    public ActionResult Pay(string id)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("EveryView", "Account");;
    }
```

Comment: @AdrianMole and Hamid Jolany, does this only point out a possible problem or also provide a solution? I can't tell. Is "check the event" only a way to find out or is that the solution? (No sarcasm here, I admit at not having enough technical knowledge and only propose to improve the impression this gives.) So please consider providing a more detailed explanation and solution.

Comment: @Yunnosch I intervened merely to make the 'rhetorical question' a statement. (As I've been 'told' to do by a moderator when previously flagging such as "not an answer.")

Comment: @AdrianMole I understand and I was on the verge of doing something similar. But my question remains. A piece of code which demonstrates the event checking and explains how it avoids the bypassing. That would look like an obviously helpful answer to me.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes I had a similar experience, where a (in my opinion more blatanlty actually question asking) post got a NAA answer rejected. So now I am extremely careful to watch out for rhetorical questions in answers. I still believe the flag rejection was in error, but what it taught me is actually valuable. Let's walk together, buddy. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Comment all loaded Scripts and try again.some script Interference by this object